# Set object correctly in a layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@layout/bginset2" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTripName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trip Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#2B00E4"
            android:layout_above="@+id/etShowLog"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTripName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etShowLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:lines="20"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnClear" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:background="@drawable/otherbuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear Trip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:background="@drawable/otherbuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Trip"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows up on my phone like this:

[image]

Why does the `Trip Name` appear so low and why is the text so close to the left?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have conflicting properties in your `EditText`

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:lines="22"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvTripName"  // here
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    // and here
```

You are telling it to be to the left of your `TextView` which is aligned left but also telling it to be aligned right of parent.

Comment: I updated my Question with the changes. please let me know why the textbox is so low and the text comes too much to the left.

Comment: Take out this line from `TextView` `android:layout_above="@+id/etShowLog"` There might be more but see what that does

Comment: In `EditText` change your padding to `layout_marginLeft` and `2dp` isn't very much. Make it maybe 20 and see how it looks

Comment: `android:marginLeft="2dp"` is giving me: `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'marginLeft' in package 'android'`

Comment: `android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"`

Comment: Wow... silly Me! Do you know why the textbox does not align with the text on the left. Is it because of the height?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not really sure why that is. You could try using default text size and see what happens. Maybe add `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` Play with that number a little and see what happens

Comment: I guess it's fine for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
    you can keep your cursor according to your choice by using this 
    EditText.setSelection(int index)
and for Trip name..just put Textview and edittext inside one layout
like

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTripName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:text="Trip Name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#2B00E4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etShowLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnClear"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:lines="20"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="Clear Trip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="Save Trip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

Hope this will work for u..
```

Comment: I tried putting them inside `LinearLayout` within the `RelativeLayout` but it did not work unfortunately and messed up my layout

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am checking it now :)

Comment: That had the same affect as keeping all RelativeLayout. I guess I will keep the little space. Thanks for taking the effort though :)